# Control SVG component css attributes when using use xlink?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG added inline to my HTML like so:

```
<body>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
    <defs>
      <g id="my_element">
        <polygon points="10 4829 45 294"/>
        <polygon points="30 390 93 20"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
...
```

Later in my html, I reference the svg element like so:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 256" class="style1"><use xlink:href="#my_element"></use></svg>
```

This works perfectly. If I have multiple groups in my svg, I can insert them into the HTML simply by referencing their group id (`#my_element`).

Also, I am able to make CSS changes to each SVG on the fly, like so:

```
svg.style1 {
  fill: red;
}
```

However, this is where my problem is. I can't seem to make CSS attribute changes to the individual components of the SVG. This doesn't work:

```
svg.style1 polygon {
  stroke: purple;
  fill: yellow;
}
```

I can obviously make these changes directly in the SVG, but I need to be able to insert multiple SVGs of the same `#my_element` and control the colors on an individual level. If I made the changes on the SVG itself, then all the elements would have the same colors no matter which style I applied to the SVG. So I need to be able to do stuff like this:

```
svg.style1 polygon {
  stroke: purple;
  fill: yellow;
}

svg.style2 polygon {
  stroke: red;
  fill: white;
}
```

Can this be done? Is it possible to control CSS attributes of individual SVG components when using the `use xlink:href` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

`<use>` element in SVG does not support `class` attribute, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674240/304371

Simple grouping resolves this issue:

```
<g id="wheel_front" class="spin">
   <use xlink:href="#wheelBase"  />
</g>
```